# Is the relation "slope=velocity" mathematically valid?

Tags: kinematics, vectors, velocity, differentiation, calculus

$\text{Slope= tan(angle with respect to positive X-axis)= scalar output}$

$\text{velocity= a vector }$

[image: graph]

Source: Hugh D Young_ Roger A Freedman - University Physics with Modern Physics In SI Units (2019, Pearson) Page-67

Then, doubts are;

1.Is the relation "Slope of tangent=instantaneous x-velocity" valid, as it would mean "scalar=vector"?

2.Even if I write "Slope of tangent=instantaneous x-speed", if the tangent makes obtuse angle slope will be negative, and we know that instantaneous speed is magnitude of instantaneous velocity, which makes instantaneous speed a positive term. So, what exactly does the slope give?

Extra information:[image]

Source: Hugh D Young_ Roger A Freedman - University Physics with Modern Physics In SI Units (2019, Pearson) Page-67

Similar confusion arises in,$\text{ "Area under a x-t graph = change in x-velocity from time 0 to time t"}$, with right hand side vector and left hand side (area) as scalar. I think answer to the original question, provides solution to this confusion as well.

Comment: 3blue1brown has a series of calculus videos that answers conceptual questions like this. The first is [The Essence of Calculus, Chapter 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUvTyaaNkzM&t=25s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind there is a difference between a *vector* and a *component* of a vector. The velocity is a vector, the x-component of the velocity (or the "$x$-velocity" in the language your book uses) is just a component of a vector, which is a scalar.

The *velocity vector* can be expanded in terms of *unit vectors* $\mathbf{e}_x, \mathbf{e}_y, \mathbf{e}_z$ (which satisfy $\mathbf{e}_x\cdot \mathbf{e}_x=1, \mathbf{e}_x\cdot \mathbf{e}_y=0$, etc):
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{v}=v_x \mathbf{e}_x + v_y \mathbf{e}_y + v_z \mathbf{e}_z
\end{equation}
The slope of the line you wrote down gives you $v_x$, which is a scalar given by $v_x=\mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{e}_x$. This quantity is a scalar, so there's no problem setting it equal to a slope. It is also a *signed* quantity, so it's not a speed (there's no requirement that $v_x>0$).

Comment: A component of a vector is a vector in its own right.  Otherwise, you couldn't add vector components to arrive at a resultant.

Comment: @DavidWhite $v_x=\mathbf{v}\cdot{e}_x$ is a scalar, not a vector, and this is the quantity I mean by "the $x$ component of $\mathbf{v}$" (I also think this is standard usage). Of course $v_x \mathbf{e}_x$ is a vector but I would not refer to this as the $x$ component of $\mathbf{v}$.

Comment: @DavidWhite "CAUTION: Components are not vectors", I just copy-pasted from the same book mentioned in question (Page 42). In general "component of a vector" means "scalar components" and "vector components(needs to explicitly mentioned) implies "vector components", this is the term you have mentioned as "A component of a vector..."

Comment: @Sahil, if the vector component has a magnitude (it surely does) and if the vector component has a direction (it should), it qualifies as a vector.  If you are just talking about the magnitude of a vector component, that is a scalar.  If that quote is from your book, then the book's authors are not using the word "component" the same way that I used it during the 13 years that I was teaching physics to high school students, and they are not using that word the same way that I have seen it used in every other physics book that I have read or used.

Comment: @DavidWhite, From what I have learnt using the book, Magnitude is a positive entity, scalar on the other hand can be positive or negative. Vector component is a vector, scalar component(generally termed as "component") is a scalar.

Comment: I've never seen the phrase "scalar component" used in a physics book, so just be aware that the terminology used by other authors may be different than that used by the authors of the book you are using.

Comment: The components of vectors are just numbers. $(a_1 ,a_2, a_3)=a_1 \hat{x} +a_2 \hat{y} +a_3 \hat{z}$ is a vector. The set of components $\{a_1 ,a_2, a_3\}$ is not a vector. $a_1$ is just a number. The reason they make a fuss over this seemingly trivial distinction is that people don't realize that numbers have to transform the right way in order to be a vector. This distinction matters when you move to curved spaces and the same $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ corresponds to different vectors depending on where $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ is in space.

Comment: If we really want to be very precise, then I admit I am a little uncomfortable calling $v_x$ a scalar, even though it is certainly a real number. The reason is that if you transform $\mathbf{v}$ into a different basis, the components will change. However, if we *define* $v_x$ as a dot product, $v_x\equiv\mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{e}_x$, then $v_x$ really is a scalar. However this is all at a higher level than what the OP needs for his question so I didn't want to get into this in my answer.

Comment: @ExpertNonExpert $\mathbf{e}_x$ is just the name for a specific vector, so $\mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{e}_x$ is the dot product of two vectors and thus is a scalar. We just have to be careful to interpret $v_x$ as the dot product of $\mathbf{v}$ with the vector $\mathbf{e}_x$, and not "the first component of $\mathbf{v}$ in an arbitrary basis." So long as we are consistent, this is fine. But again, I think this is at a higher level than what the OP was asking.

Comment: On the other hand, looking at quora (admittedly not a very reliable source ;)), "vector components" can be vectors, scalars, or both: https://www.quora.com/Are-vector-components-scalar . So, there are many different opinions :)  will just sidestep this and stick with $\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{e}_x$ which is definitely a scalar.

Comment: Ok. It's a scalar, by that definition, but it is a scalar telling you something about a specific basis which is not what you usually want from a scalar in practice, I believe.

Comment: @ExpertNonExpert Sure. I don't think we disagree with each other. However, I do think if I had gone into this it would have made the answer twice as long and not addressed the main confusion of the original question.